# Did Putin literally say, "Those who serve us with poison will eventually swallow it and poison themselves"?

Tags: перевод

It's going around that Putin said:

> 'Those who serve us with poison will eventually swallow it and poison themselves'.

---

see:

- [Darude](http://darudemag.com/2018/03/putin-those-who-serve-us-with-poison-will-eventually-swallow-it-and-poison-themselves/)

> Putin: “Those who serve us with poison will eventually swallow it and poison themselves.”

- [Attention To The Unseen](https://attentiontotheunseen.com/2018/03/08/putin-those-who-serve-us-with-poison-will-eventually-swallow-it-and-poison-themselves/)

> Putin: ‘Those who serve us with poison will eventually swallow it and poison themselves’

---

After Viktor Sukhodrev's mishaps with Russian translation I'm skeptical to accept it at its face-value.

Is this an accurate translation? What is that phrase that he used? What does it mean?

Or is this just another «Мы вас похороним!»?

---

edit: This seems to be the interview here: https://youtu.be/w7swxH6RjBY?t=50s it's dubbed over in English though, not sure how hard that makes it to hear.

As quoted by [facenews](https://www.facenews.ua/columns/2018/319814/) the original Russian seems to be:

> "Те, кто капает куда-то яд, сами его и проглотят в конце концов, сами этим ядом и отравятся".

капает seems to be a form of [капать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) meaning:

> to drip, drop, spill

Where the English says:

> serve us with

I'm quite confused what drip has to do with serving someone.

Comment: This is a translation of what? I don't see the original Russian text in your question.

Comment: @Dmitry I edited the question with a youtube link, not sure how good it is though.

Comment: either 100% correct or not you can never cast doubt on his ability to be quite nasty with his manner of speech, the more accurate translation by Dmitry is nasty enough

Comment: this is a service that helps Russian learners to learn Russian, not to check up correctness of translations.

Comment: @shabunc If I provide more "prior research effort," would you re-open the question?

Comment: @user3306356 are you learning Russian - if yes, can you please explain what exactly don't you like in the translations provided, what would be your thoughts on how this is should be translated and why you are still having some doubts.

Comment: @shabunc I've edited it now, please let me know if that is sufficient enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recognized correctly, Putin said:

> Те, кто капают куда-то яд, сами его и проглотят в конце концов, сами этим ядом и отравятся.

This could be translated as:

> Those who drip poison somewhere will eventually swallow it and poison themselves.

Comment: I suggest "Those who drop poison into something". In constrast "drip poison somewhere" sounds like it is leaking or rolling off someone's body and getting the floor wet.